# Copying files from subfolders and main directory to another location c#

Tags: c#

First off I would like to say I love this site. It has been very helpful through out the years.

Currently I have a folder on my desktop `C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder` and inside this folder on my desktop I have a subfolder or directory called DVNSHP012 which contains `xml` files. `C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder` contains `xml` files as well.

I can currently transfer the `xml` files from the main directory of `C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder` only with the following code.

```
//Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(DESKTOPLHA54U4, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(DESKTOPLHA54U4, path), true);
```

The above code again only transfers from the main directory of `C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New` folder and not the entire including `C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder\DVNSHP012`. I'm currently trying to search for all subdirectories including the main directory for `.xml` files then transferring those `xml's` to `\downloads\`

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            {
                TestWebMsgApp.WebMsgBox.Show("Folder created in root of drive");
            }
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(DESKTOPLHA54U4, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(DESKTOPLHA54U4, path));
                if (Directory.Exists(DESKTOPLHA54U4))
                {
                    //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
                    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(DESKTOPLHA54U4, "*.xml",
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(DESKTOPLHA54U4, path), true);
                }
            }
```

I've also tried searching all over google and as well as SO before posting here but nothing seemed to pertain to my specific issue. Is there a way to search for all *.xml files including the sub-directories? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Browse how? With windows explorer?

Comment: Browse with an open file dialog box. My apologies I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine, you just have to add code that creates (sub)directories in the target folder, because `File.Copy()` doesn't create them if they don't already exist. This works for me:

```
var DESKTOPLHA54U4 = @"C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder\";
var path = @"C:\downloads\";

foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(DESKTOPLHA54U4, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // Ensure that target subdirectory exists
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath.Replace(DESKTOPLHA54U4, path)));

    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(DESKTOPLHA54U4, path), true);
}
```

Alternatively, you can create method that copies directory (and subdirectorties) recursively:

```
public static void CopyDirectory(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory, string fileSearchPattern)
{
    // Ensures that (sub)target directory exists.
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);

    foreach (string subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sourceDirectory))
    {
        // Recursively call CopyDirectory() for all subdirectories
        CopyDirectory(
            subDir,
            Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(subDir)),
            fileSearchPattern);
    }

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        File.Copy(
            file,
            Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file)),
            true);
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
CopyDirectory(@"C:\Users\Donjf\Desktop\New folder\", @"C:\downloads\", "*.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and reply. I've searched everywhere literally for this answer. +1 from me for the answer. Again thank you for your time and effort to answering the question.

Comment: I ended up changing only one line of code from `    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))` to `    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))` and it pulled xml files from sub-directories as well. again thank you for your help :D